# Why does Bison put the entire match in the variable?

Tags: c, bison, flex-lexer

I am trying to use `flex` and `bison` to create a 6502 assembler (for learning purposes). My flex tokens are:

```
[a-zA-Z]{3} {
    yylval.a = yytext;
    return MNEMONIC;
}

\$[0-9a-fA-F]{2} {
    yylval.zp = strtol(yytext + 1, NULL, 16);
    return ZEROPAGE;
}
```

and the Bison grammar is this:

```
program:
    program expression '\n' { }
|   program '\n' { }
|   program error '\n'      { yyerrok; }
|   /* NOTHING */
;

expression:
     MNEMONIC { printf("I: %s\n", $1); }
|    MNEMONIC ZEROPAGE { printf("ZP: '%s' %d\n", $1, $2); }
;
```

For what I understand, when parsing `LDA $99` the `MNEMONIC ZEROPAGE` rule should put `LDA` in `$1` and `$99` in `$2`, but when printing, I see that `$1` is set to `LDA $99`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try `yylval = strdup(yytext);`, and don’t forget to free it somewhere. `yytext` is a pointer into the input buffer, and *flex* puts a trailing null there temporarily for the action, but takes it out again.

Comment: I meant`yylval.a = strdup(yytext);`, of course.